# How to autostart a .sh after login?

Tags: gnome

I have made a .sh (which works) to run a mono program. How do I make it run every time I login? (and display in a terminal, not just run in background)
Ubuntu server 12.04 with Unity desktop.

Answer (score 4):

- First make your script executable.

```
chmod +x /path/to/script
```

- Open Startup Applications, from the cog menu present at the upper right corner.

[image: Cog menu]

- Click on *Add*.

[image: Startup Applications Dialog]

- Fill in all the details and click *Add*.

[image: Add Startup Application Preferences]

- Logout and login back to check.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can start any script by navigating to`System \ Preferences\ Sessions menu` item and then just adding the command or the script you want to rin
[image]

Comment: is this 12.04 ? it's unity in 12.04, not gnome 2

Comment: sorry, I meant unity.

Comment: ok sorry for i took it for gnome. Well unity has its own preferences. The startup application in unity can be found at topbar as a drop-down menu option of power button, located before the shotdown options and all.

Answer (score 0):

You could use $HOME/.bashrc 
It is parsed and run like a script, every time bash starts. Bash is the default shell for Ubuntu.

I have a script that saves every command line I've used, like this:

```
$ tail -2 $HOME/.bashrc
/usr/local/bin/backup-historial.sh &
```

Comment: So I have to put my scirpt in .bashrc which is in /home? I tried this and it didn't work.

Comment: bad idea for those who may ssh into a box

Answer (score 0):

Go into the Startup Applications dialog, click Add, give it a name and in Command put

```
gnome-terminal -e yourscript.sh
```

You can check it works first by running `gnome-terminal -e yourscript.sh` from a terminal (it should then open another terminal).

Answer (score 0):

Put your script in a file (we call it yourscript.sh) and make in executable:

```
#!/bin/bash
#put your script here
echo "Press enter to close"
read line
```

Then open /etc/rc.local file using a text editor:

```
sudo gedit /etc/rc.local
```

Finally add the following code in the rc.local just before "exit 0" command:

```
gnome-terminal -e "./dirtoyourscript/yourscript.sh"

exit 0
```

Have a nice time.

Comment: I would believe, `/etc/rc.local` runs before X does (and thus, even before the login greeter); which  means `/etc/rc.local` is not appropriate for doing things "after login".

Answer (score 0):

if you kown how to handle crontab , add this line :

```
@reboot gnome-terminal -e "./dirtoyourscript/yourscript.sh"
```

if you don't know , 
execute the following commands to edit your crontab

```
EDITOR=gedit 
export EDITOR
alias editor=$EDITOR
crontab -e
```